# i have an error while import the sql file

Tags: mysql, import

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` varchar(240) NOT NULL,
    `email` varchar(240) NOT NULL,
    `password` varchar(240) NOT NULL,
    `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;
```

Comment: Sigh.  You mind sharing *what* the error is?  And *what* you're trying to import into?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the table name has something to do.I see that you chose the name "USERS".Perhaps is a reserved word!What database are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the first part:

```
    CREATE TABLE users(
    id int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, 
    name VARCHAR(240) NOT NULL, 
    email VARCHAR(240) NOT NULL, 
    password VARCHAR(240) NOT NULL)
    ..
    .
    .
```

Comment: I don't see any downvotes, but what exactly is this fixing?  It doesn't even appear to be in the right language from the OP's post

Comment: In SQL server you use identity NOT Auto_increment.

Comment: does the original code look like SQL Server to you?

Comment: The tag is email integration.. the subject says SQL ... I know when they use auto increment.. but when they come from mysql world they assume it is the same as sql.

Comment: Let me try again:  the original post uses `backticks` around all of their names, and additionally specifies the `MyISAM engine`, both of which are MySQL and *not* SQL Server.  Their question is extremely vague, and doesn't even state what the problem is, so how can you even assume they're trying to convert to SQL Server?

Comment: NOT when I first checked. It was edited ... My response as above again... copy and paste think it should work.

Comment: It was simply poorly indented; if you had clicked "Edit" and actually looked at the code, the backticks were there the entire time, as was the ISAM engine.  I've spent enough energy here, I'm out of here.

Comment: Seriously? You should go up and click on edit that was done 28 min ago. The post was 58 min ago from NOW. By the way you should know these things about stackoverflow better.

Comment: Yes, seriously.  Look at the damn edit history.  Click here:  http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26161376/revisions, click "Edit" under version 1, and tell me what you see.  Do you see backticks?  Do you see ISAM engine?  Because I sure do.  By the way, I *do* know how these things work on Stack Overflow, do you?

Comment: This is what I see.. I have my glasses on do you? By the way my answer is to original post. Look highlighted.

           http://postimg.org/image/4etwin12d/